# Hiding move semantics behind single function

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

e.g. I have a function that can handle `const T &` and `T &&` values:

```
template <typename T>
/* ... */ foo(const T &) {
std::cout << "const T & as arg" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
/* ... */ foo(T &&) {
std::cout << "T && as arg" << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way that I can write a single function, that handles both types automatically? As in:

```
template <typename T>
/* ... */ bar(T t) {
    foo(t);
}
```

So that:

```
T a;
bar(a); // Handles as const T &
T b;
bar(std::move(b)); // Handles as T &&
```

Thank you!

Comment: See `std::forward` and universal references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward

Comment: Do you want to allow `const T c; bar(c);`?

Comment: Are you sure your existing functions work as you think? `foo(a)` and `foo(std::move(b))` will call the same function.

Comment: Regarding to Chris comment, note that your second overload doesn't take rvalues only, its an universal reference, so the `"T && as arg"` assumption is false.

Answer (score 8):

You can use reference collapsing and [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to *forward* the argument to the `foo` function:

```
template <typename T>
/* ... */ bar(T&& t) {
    foo(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Please notice that your `foo` function will accept rvalues, constant lvalues and non-const lvalues. As an example, given:

```
const int x = 456;
int y = 123;
```

then:

```
foo(123);   // foo(T&&)
foo(x);     // foo(const T&)
foo(y);     // foo(T&&)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/877d870f8c522f3e)